# using .htaccess stop specific zip download without referrer and/or offsite hotlinking

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way with htaccess rules to stop the download of a **specific** zip file unless its been linked through the site. Ie. Stop people from copy and pasting of link or pasting link onto address bar or another site.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to regular hotlink protection should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule filename\.zip$ - [F]
```

Essentially, specify your domain, and if the referrer doesn't match it will return a 403 - forbidden page instead of the file.

Be careful with referrers though, as they may not always be set.